# What does multi threading layout look like in RAM

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, memory-layout

I'm trying to figure out what the multi threading layout looks like in RAM. I got the image below from Google:

[image]

It seems that this image tells me that each thread has its own stack, which is all we know.

So I think a multi-threading process needs more memory spaces.

Then I do such a test with C++11:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code above and get an executable file with `12K`-size.

```
void func()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    int i = 1;
    cout << &i << endl;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

After adding a function, the size becomes `16K`.

```
void func()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    int i = 1;
    cout << &i << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(func);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

After adding a thread, the size becomes `52K`.

```
void func()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    int i = 1;
    cout << &i << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(func);
    thread t2(func);
    thread t3(func);
    thread t4(func);
    thread t5(func);
    thread t6(func);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    t6.join();

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I add 5 more threads, the size is still `52K`.

Now I'm confused. Each thread has its own stack, this is for sure. But why can't adding thread increase the size of executable file? What does multi threading layout look like?

Comment: Runtime memory allocation (and layout) is different from program executable size and “the stack” is not part of a program executable.. Imagine if there is a loop that starts 2 or 100 threads based on a command-line option. Surely a runtime option can’t change the already compiled executable size! The increase in program size is based on the new features used, *including template instantiations*, required static linkage, and code written; the lines to “add *more* threads” increase the program size as well; just on the order of bytes, which goes unnoticed.

Comment: tldr; executable_image_size != RAM_or_memory_usage

Comment: @user2864740  So for the runtime memory allocation of a multi threading process, each thread has its own stack? meaning that all of threads will possess their own physical memory or the threads may use/share the same physical memory?

Comment: Each thread has its *own* stack space - such that they can modify their own stacks without affecting other threads. Memory and resources (including loaded program code) are otherwise generally shared.

Comment: Note that in the images, “text + data” represents the program executable - which doesn’t change regardless of the number of threads (where each thread has it’s own stack while sharing the same “text + data” and heap, as shown in the image to the right).

Comment: Also, while the image model shown is relatively easy to use as a base model, it’s *not* precise as to modern implementations - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization for one way this model is altered.